# The Google Service Account credential has not been configured correctly - APK publisher via Jenkins

Tags: android, apk, jenkins-plugins, google-apis-explorer, google-play-developer-api

I have configured my Jenkins job to upload signed-apks via plugin [Google Play Android Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin) to google play console.

I have also signed my apk following the description on plugin read me page.

However I keep getting:

> The Google Service Account credential 'Google Play Android Developer'
>   has not been configured correctly.Update the credential, ensuring that
>   the required data have been entered, then try again

Anything that I missed apart from the [steps](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin) followed?

Note: I have granted Admin access to the API User (Jenkins) in Play Console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After few day's efforts and splitting my jenkins job into two different parts, and trying all the hacks, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703479/gerrit-googleplay-publisher-plugin-credentials-has-not-been-configured-correctly) solved my problem.

**I simply had to downgrade [token-macro to 1.10](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/token-macro/), [google-play-publisher to 1.5](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/google-play-android-publisher/) and [Oauth 0.3](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/google-oauth-plugin/) plugin in Jenkins.**

To publish my signed-apks to play console via Jenkins.
Its known bug and still exists in latest version of google-play-publisher plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution would remove the GIT section from Jenkins Jobs. i.e: You will no longer have branch selector in your Jenkins Job neither you will have the Git Polling working.
I can say that this solution is not working.

Comment: Yasir, the git configuration is based on Git Plugin 3.8.0 (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin). So if you see that option removed, then use git plugin to have that option again. Works for me absolutely fine.

Comment: Will be happy to share exact configs and plugin details if it still doesnt work for you. My Jenkins version is "Jenkins ver. 2.107.1"

Comment: Current Git version is dependent on other plugins which would require to downgrade all those plugins as well and the chain goes on.
Just to resolve a small issue for a single plugin, downgrading tons of other dependent plugins is not a reliable way. 
In a Shared Jenkins environment where there are multiple projects from different teams (node.js teams, angular teams, iOS teams) are running, downgrading multiple plugins could break the whole Jenkins system.

Comment: I would suggest to use Gradle plugin to publish apks to Google Play Store.

Comment: I have downgraded 3 Plugins so far. Unsure of gradle plugin, let me give it a try.

Comment: Please note that "Gradle Plugin" meant to be a plugin for Gradle not Jenkins. I added com.github.triplet.play Plugin into my build.gradle file and now i can execute the gradle task from Jenkins to publish the apk to PlayStore.

Comment: Oh yes, I had done that to directly publish. However I had multiple reasons to do it via jenkins.. I agree that downgrading plugins can lead to affect a lot of projects. Its a workaround, until I figure out the best solution.

Comment: I can't even downgrade the Oauth plugin in Jenkins now.