# Jenkins CI/CD Failed to publish to Android Playstore

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am trying to publish Android Singed apk from Jenkins v2.134, The signed apk generated successfully, (That can be manually uploaded - tested). But when it comes to publishing, it failing with below exception.

I am using JSON key to accessing Google APIs and services. And also the created user has the required permission needed. First in the default version it [showing some problem and I downgrade some version of plugins as they suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703479/gerrit-googleplay-publisher-plugin-credentials-has-not-been-configured-correctly).

**Googleplayandroidpublisher v1.5**,

**Token Macro v1.10**,

**Google OAuth v0.3**.

But getting this Exception when uploading the signed to Android Playstore

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkUploadTask.execute(ApkUploadTask.java:81)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkUploadTask.execute(ApkUploadTask.java:35)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.AbstractPublisherTask.call(AbstractPublisherTask.java:33)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkPublisher.publishApk(ApkPublisher.java:313)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkPublisher.perform(ApkPublisher.java:183)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Upload Android APK to Google Play' marked build as failure 
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Found the solution yet?

Comment: no, I got frustrated then started using https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher

Comment: I got the solution though.

Comment: Can you please share your's, it would be a great help and I'll accept as answer.